# Can a good beer be ready in one week?

Tags: recipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Brewing with a deadline](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/brewing-with-a-deadline)

I've got a thing coming up and was wondering if I could brew a beer in time for it. It would have to be ready in 11 days. I have a keg/carbonation so we could skip the carbonating phase.

What do I need to know in order to do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/brewing-with-a-deadline

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make beer in a week.  It will, of course, depend on the style you want to brew, and you don't have time for secondary, but 9-10 days in primary and a day of force carbonation is enough time for a drinkable beer.

You'll need a simple recipe for a low to moderate strength beer.  High alcohol, dry hopping, and other post-fermentation additions are out of the question.

Expect the flavors to be a bit harsh and grainy, and the beer will still be hazy and yeasty, as eleven days isn't nearly enough time for the tastes to meld and mellow and all the yeast to flocculate, but if all else goes well, the beer should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't count on it, but maybe.  Every time I've rushed a beer I've been disappointed in the results.  Do you really want to serve people something that doesn't represent the best you can do?  Remember, the beer makes the schedule, not the calendar!

Comment: Me too.  I've had a couple of times where I brewed a beer with an even in mind (even if it's several months off), and THOSE are the batches that end up sucking the most.

Answer (score 0):

Try brewing an ale that doesn't need to clarify, like a hefeweizen, and you should be able to make it in time.